# KendoUI Bar Chart categoryAxis grouping issue

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, bar-chart

I am facing issue with categoryAxis when any one item is missing in the grouping. I have modified the code in below fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/v8tsQ/9/

I have replaced the javascript as below:-

```
var dr = 
  [{
      "currency":"AUD",
      "paymenttype":"0",
      "amount":"10"
   },
   {
      "currency":"AUD",
      "paymenttype":"3",
      "amount":"11"
   },
   {
      "currency":"CAD",
      "paymenttype":"1",
      "amount":"24"
   },
   {
      "currency":"CAD",
      "paymenttype":"0",
      "amount":"23"
   },
   {
      "currency":"CAD",
      "paymenttype":"3",
      "amount":"22"
   }]

var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: dr,
    group: {
        field: "paymenttype"
    },
    sort: [{
        field: "paymenttype",
        dir: "asc"
    }, {
        field: "currency",
        dir: "asc"
    }]

})

$("#chart").kendoChart({
    dataSource: ds,
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: 'column',
        labels: {
            visible: true,
            template: "#=kendo.format('{0:0}', value)#"
        }
    },
    legend: {
        visible: true,
        position: "bottom"
    },
    series: [{
        field: "amount"
    }],
    categoryAxis: {
        field: "currency"
    },
    tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        template: "#= dataItem.currency#"
    }
});
```

**Issue :**

The CAD currency is showing under AUD for type 1, which does not exists for currency AUD.

Please suggest. 
Thanks

Comment: I am trying to change the data source query to make it work. But seems not good for performance.

Comment: The linq solved the issue. Updated the query to send all the records even when no row in database for a currency.                                                      AUD 0 10
AUD 1 NULL
AUD 3 11
CAD 1 24
CAD 0 23
CAD 3 22